# How to make sure only single chromedriver.exe instance is running in background?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have been trying to find this out but have not had any success.

**Problem**: Whenever my selenium webdriver tests are running and get closed in between, say by mistake or someone closes chrome window, "**chromedriver.exe**" is left initialized in the background and I have to end this process manually each time because next time it is again created when tests are run.

So is there anyway I can check that the chromedriver.exe instance is already present in memory?

I am using Java and can write a script for this but I am wondering whether I can use

`public boolean isRunning()` within

```
Class DriverService

java.lang.Object
org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill the background instances by including this in your code:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Furthermore, You can use `browser.quit()`to close the windows but it is not effective all the time.